# Instant database search php, jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to make my regular search to achive instant search like googles which return the search result and you can click on that link to get to the "Search page" where it will display the full result. i followed this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AqM9U3mi9A from Helping Develop.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  function searchq (){
   var searchTxt= $("input[name='search']").val();

   $.post("instant.php", {searchVal: searchTxt}, function (output){
   $("#output").html(output) 

  });   

  }
</script>

<form action="Search_page.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="search" onkeydown="searchq();"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="" id="button" />
</form>
<div id="output">
</div>
```

**Edit:**

Problem fixed,
missed `#` before `$("output").html(output)` by correcting it, code works as intended

Comment: How did you fail? What is the situation and what is the desired output? Do you get any errors? What did you try in terms of debugging? What does your `instant.php` look like? Did you use your browsers developer tools to check if your Service works?

Comment: where is your jquery posting to

Comment: i forgot # before output in $("output").html(output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `#` in `output` selector, replace `$("output").html(output)` with `$("#output").html(output);` and try